# oracle thin driver which jar file is used?

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, thin, beanshell

I have inherited a VM (linux OS) from someone. It has a java app "bob" deployed/running inside of tomcat and oracle 11.2.0 database. I wrote a simple db connection in beanshell (lightweight of java) as following example and it executed fine however a question came to my mind.

```
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:hostname:1521:sidname","username","password");
```

I noticed that ojdbc14.jar found /somepath/tomcat/webapps/bob/WEB-INF/lib/ojdbc14.jar AND from oracle installation /somepath/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/jdbc/lib/{ojdbc5.jar,ojdbc6_g.jar,ojdbc6.jar} three ojdbc jar files found.

Which jar file in this case thin driver used in order to make database connection and successfully run sql query statement?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should get rid of `ojdbc14.jar` and `jdbc5.jar`. The first one is intended for Java **1.4**, the second one is intended for Java **5** (unless you actually use these outdated, non-supported Java versions).

If you are using Java7 then you should use `ojdbc7.jar`. If you are still using the (un-supported) Java 6, you should use `ojdbc6.jar`.

Note that the number in the file name only denotes the Java version, not the driver's version. To get that you would need to look at the MANIFEST.MF or use `DatabaseMetaData.getDriverVersion()`

Regarding the class loading in Tomcat:

Tomcat loads classes from either `$CATALINA_HOME/lib`, `$CATALINA_HOME/lib/ext` or in one of the deployed webbaps in the `WEB-INF/lib` directory.

So in your case, the outdated, obsolete `/somepath/tomcat/webapps/bob/WEB-INF/lib/ojdbc14.jar` is being used.

You should replace with an up-to-date version.

Comment: i see. thank you for answering my question. I am using Java 6 so will replace ojdbc14.jar with ojdbc6.jar. have a blessed day!